# Preserving Field Name & Alias in Select() function

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, select, alias

I am unable to get an output using `arcpy.analysis.Select()` where the field aliases and names are preserved.

```
from arcpy.analysis import *

Select("Input.shp", "Output.shp", "FLOOR= 0")
```

The codeblock above gives columns names based on the table name such as `Input_1`, `Input_2`, `Input_3`, etc... is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What is your `Input`?  A shapefile or geodatabase?

Comment: shapefile, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update to this issue, the solution is listed here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000008000000

You basically need to set `arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False` as it is True by default, this will preserve all original field names.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles don't store aliases. If you're OK with your new field names being close to your aliases, but restricted to shapefile field name limits, you might be able to get close by copying the output shapefile to a geodatabase feature class, renaming the fields with `AlterField_management`, and exporting it back out to shapefile.

Comment: Where is the tabular data associated with a shapefile stored then?

Comment: In the dbf file, which only stores a field name, but not an alias.